# Error when installing Microsoft SQL Server - no_pubkey

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

There is this error and I tried to change my Dockerfile but nothing seems to work.

I'm currently on MacOS 14.3 and working with Docker for Desktop

Heres part of my file that's probably causing problems:

```
FROM php:8.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
  && apt-get -y install libicu-dev libonig-dev libzip-dev gnupg \
  unzip locales libxml2-dev wget software-properties-common supervisor gcc make autoconf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release gnupg \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https

RUN gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key EB3E94ADBE1229CF \
    && gpg -a --export EB3E94ADBE1229CF | apt-key add - && apt-get update

RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

and there is error that keeps on poping up:

```
2.368 Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease [6537 B]
2.419 Err:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease
2.419   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
2.428 Reading package lists...
2.631 W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
2.631 E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease' is not signed.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release gnupg     && echo \"deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
```

Comment: Aside... if you`docker run -it --rm php:8.3-fpm cat /etc/os-release` you'll see that it's using Debian 12 Bookworm. You should use Debian 12 repo references instead of the Debian 10 Buster repo references you're currently using.

Comment: Did you notice the warning, `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`? This is because the `apt-key` tool has been deprecated since Debian 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me so am posting how my file looks after many iterations which is working for me.

```
FROM php:8.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
  && apt-get -y install libicu-dev libonig-dev libzip-dev gnupg \
  unzip locales libxml2-dev wget software-properties-common supervisor gcc `enter code here`make autoconf
    
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes gnupg2 libgssapi-krb5-2 unixodbc-dev

RUN curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg \
&&  curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
&&  apt-get update

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q --allow-unauthenticated \
    git \
    sudo
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/zsh linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN CI=1 /bin/bash -c "$(sudo curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
USER root
RUN chown -R $CONTAINER_USER: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
ENV PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:${PATH}"
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(brew update)"
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(brew doctor)"
USER root
RUN  /bin/bash -c "$(brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release)" \
&&  /bin/bash -c "$(brew update)" \
&&  /bin/bash -c "$(HOMEBREW_ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools)" \
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating new `Dockerfile`s I recommend using `docker run` to build out and test your installation steps, because many warnings and some errors are hidden away by the `docker build` and `docker-compose` tools.

The way Debian manages package signing keys has changed over time. This old way of installing keys using `apt-key` no longer works:

```bash
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key EB3E94ADBE1229CF \
    && gpg -a --export EB3E94ADBE1229CF | apt-key add -
```

Although updated from this, even Microsoft's instructions at [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline) are out of date and incorrect for Debian 12:

```bash
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
```

For Debian 12 specifically this doesn't work because the repo at https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list contains a reference to a specific local .gpg file:

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/12/prod bookworm main
```

To make this work you need the following command instead (thanks to [Debian 12 public key is not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328834/debian-12-public-key-is-not-available)):

```bash
curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
```

Testing with `docker run -it -u 0 --rm php:8.3-fpm /bin/bash` a complete recipe for Debian 12, based in Microsoft's instructions but actually working, looks like the following:

```bash
# Install prerequisites
apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes gnupg2 libgssapi-krb5-2 unixodbc-dev

# Register Microsoft's repo for Debian 12
curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update

# Install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and tools (sqlcmd, etc.)
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```